# Not able to hook up the Effects on app.module.ts.Showing Static injector error when trying to add the effect

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am learning the ngRx Store and hence building a small project using ngRx/Store,Effects.
There are two parts of the application .One deals with books and the other deals with posts .For the books part the data is being fetched synchronously and hence has no problems associated with it.
In the Posts section my intention is to fetch the data from an external API asynchronously using ngRx/Effects. But when I am just writing a bare bones effect and trying to hook it up in my app.module.ts I am getting this error.
[image: Error Image]

Below is my App.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms'
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BookListComponent } from './components/book-list/book-list.component';

import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/Store';
import { AddBookComponent } from './add-book/add-book.component';
import { PostListComponent } from './post-list/post-list.component';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http'
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { PostEffects } from './Effects/posts.effects';
import { reducers } from './Store/app.reducer';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BookListComponent,
    AddBookComponent,
    PostListComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([PostEffects]),

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is the bare minimum effects I have put together.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Effect, Actions } from '@ngrx/effects';
@Injectable()
export class PostEffects {
  @Effect()
  getPosts ;
  constructor(private actions$: Actions) {
  }
}
```

this is my app state reducer

```
import { State } from '../reducers/books.reducers';
import { postState } from '../reducers/posts.reducers';
import { ActionReducerMap } from '@ngrx/Store';
import * as bookListReducer from '../reducers/books.reducers';
import * as postListReducer from '../reducers/posts.reducers';

export interface AppState {
    bookList: State,
    postList : postState
}
export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
    bookList: bookListReducer.booksReducer,
    postList : postListReducer.postsReducer
  }
```

Can somebody help me out ?Thanks in advance

Comment: The only thing I see is: `import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/Store';` Try: `import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';` lowercase "s" in "store"

Comment: @Brandon Thanks a ton !!!.That fixed the issue

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to help.